# how to link main.py class and my.kv rule?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

i wonder whether there is a convenient method to create widget class in main.py and link it to my.kv ,it is sccessful in MyLayout but fail in MyModalView

First,following is my code

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView


class MyModalView(ModalView):
    pass

class MyLayout(GridLayout):
    a1 = MyModalView()

    def btn1(self):
        self.a1.open()
        #self.a1.dismiss()


class Myapp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Myapp().run()
```

my.kv

```
<MyModalView>:

    Button:
        text:'starting point'


<MyLayout>:
    rows:2

    Button:
        text: 'press me'
        on_press: root.btn1()

    Label:
        text: 'hello world
```

when I press the button,the pycharm show this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb6Bh.png)

but the result which I want is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYxwB.png)

I change main.py code to show this result which I want,but I really want to know is it possible to change my.kv only to show the same result?

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.button import Button



class MyModalView(ModalView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModalView,self).__init__()
        self.add_widget(Button(text='apple'))
    pass


class MyLayout(GridLayout):
    a1 = MyModalView()

    def btn1(self):
        self.a1.open()


class Myapp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Myapp().run()
```

my.kv

```
<MyLayout>:
    rows:2

    Button:
        text: 'press me'
        on_press: root.btn1()

    Label:
        text: 'hello world'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the `MyModalView` from within the `kv` by using `Factory`:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyModalView>:

    Button:
        text:'starting point'


<MyLayout>:
    rows:2

    Button:
        text: 'press me'
        on_press: Factory.MyModalView().open()

    Label:
        text: 'hello world'
```